# regex - How do you use the 'nth capturing group' (\n) expression in a Lookbehind?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Is there any way to use the 'nth capturing group' expression (i.e. '\1', '\2', '\3', etc), in a regex Lookbehind?

Something like this: `(?<=\1)([a-z])`

I know it's possible to use it in a Lookahead: `([a-z])(?=\1)`

I'm testing my regex patterns with an online tool and it keeps giving me errors whenever I use the '\n' expression in a Lookbehind.

This makes me think that either it requires a special syntax, or it just isn't possible.

If it truly isn't possible to use the '\n' expression in a Lookbehind, are there any alternatives that would work just as well?

**Edit:** My goal is to be able to *dynamically* test for the character that is before the current character.

My specific use case is that I'm searching for all characters that are not preceded nor followed by the same character as itself.

For example, given these strings:

```
// Should match 'b', because it is neither followed nor preceded by a 'b'.
// Should match 'd' for the same reason
aabccd 

// Should match 'y'
xxyzz

// Should match 'l' and 'o'
lmmmnnopppp
```

I figured the best way to do this would be to match all characters using `([a-z])`, but to only select the ones that were not preceded by the same character using `(?<!\1)` and not followed by the same character using: `(?!\1)`.

The complete pattern would look something like this: `/(?<!\1)([a-z])(?!\1)/g`

However, if 'nth capturing group' expressions can't be used in Lookebehind assertions and there is no equivalent substitute, then I will have to look for another strategy.

Comment: Sure can, I'll add some in.  The reason I didn't add in any information about my particular use case, is because I considered the topic/tool to be rather general, so I was afraid that somebody might edit out my particular problem as being superfluous and/or anecdotal.  I figured the question had less to do with my particular problem than it did with how to use/substitute a particular feature in regex.  Nonetheless, I'll add in some context for my particular problem.  If you're able to help me at all after I do so, it would be greatly appreciated. Oh, and thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It can be done using fixed length look behinds, I'll show you how ..

Comment: There you go, posted a solution. In general, this is fairly easy since the characters are really a fixed length. Anything of variable length and you'd have to use Dot-Net which is squirly on variable length look behinds.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine this regex  `(a.*).+?(?<!\1)..`
you see that capture group 1 can be a variable length.

So, most regex engines that support *only* fixed width
look behind assertions, won't let you use a backreference
inside a look behind assertion. Even if the capture group is fixed `(a)`
it still won't let you do it.

---

The alternative can vary from case to case but usually it involves using a look ahead assertion.

---

Fwiw

`(?<=\1)([a-z])` is directly equivalent to `(?<=([a-z]))\1`

***update***

> Edit: My goal is to be able to dynamically test for the character that is before the current character.
>
> My specific use case is that I'm searching for all characters that are not preceded nor followed by the same character as itself.

You can do this two nearly identical ways.
They both involve an extra check for the boundary
on the look behind, the look ahead is no problem.

Most people don't know that you can imbed/nest assertions
and they are like effective at changing the direction of
examination by actually running on a separate stack with
it's own code position and everything.

That lets you do tricky stuff like this:

**Way 1** - Using a Branch Reset `(?| )`
nothing special, it just reuses common capture groups.
Just easier to read. Requires PCRE or Perl or Ruby.

`(?|(?<=\b()(?=([a-z])))\2(?!\2)|(?<=([a-z])(?!\1)(?=([a-z])))\2(?!\2))`

https://regex101.com/r/s6Z8uV/1

Expanded

```
 (?|
      (?<=
           \b 
           ( )                           # (1)
           (?=
                ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
           )
      )
      \2 
      (?! \2 )
   |  
      (?<=
           ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
           (?! \1 )
           (?=
                ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
           )
      )
      \2 
      (?! \2 )
 )
```

**Way 2** - Using nothing special.

`(?:(?<=\b()(?=([a-z])))\2(?!\2)|(?<=([a-z])(?!\3)(?=([a-z])))\4(?!\4))`

https://regex101.com/r/D0lTUF/1

Expanded

```
 (?:
      (?<=
           \b 
           ( )                           # (1)
           (?=
                ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
           )
      )
      \2 
      (?! \2 )
   |  
      (?<=
           ( [a-z] )                     # (3)
           (?! \3 )
           (?=
                ( [a-z] )                     # (4)
           )
      )
      \4 
      (?! \4 )
 )
```